# Add animation at certain frame

Tags: animation

I got this animation:
[image]

And I'd like to add another animation +- at frame 300, but it starts at the beginning. How can I do it?

Comment: "but it starts at the beginning", what do you mean? What you show is the Timeline, it's not the window where you create animations, to do that you need to open the Dopesheet window

Comment: When I start filming, that movement begins as well

Comment: perhaps what you need is to use the NLA editor, you should check some tutos about it, it will allows you to create an animation in the Dopesheet (Action Editor mode), then move it wherever you want along the time

Comment: I don't know... What I'm trying to say is: I want to start an animation at frame 200 instead of 0... Maybe drag the key? I don't know, I'm beginner on blender

Comment: if you mean you want the cursor to start playing at frame 300, you can put your cursor at 300, press alt A, and then esc to go back and stop at 300. Or you can put your cursor at frame 300 and press S (for start, and E for end) to change the whole animation length. If you mean you want to create an animation that will only begin at 300 you can either create it from frame 300, or crate it from frame 1 and move it in the Dopesheet window, or create it from frame 1 and move its strip on the NLA editor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you're going to say, just type "300" on the third text field (in the photo, the one with "1")